# Why can't it just highlight the new data?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a refreshing function which checks fresh data in the database every 60 seconds and, if found, adds it to the list.

I want it to be highlighted for a few seconds when it brings it on auto-refresh, yet it does nothing. It either highlights all the list, or nothing!

```
function clock(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "update.php",
        data: "row=" + num,
        cache: false,  
        success: function(data){ 
            $("#ads").prepend(data);
            $(data).effect('highlight', {}, 5000);
        }
    });
}
setInterval(clock, 60000);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does update.php do? What happens when you replace it with a static fake-data file?

Comment: Independent of your question: When you really are doing it for 24h straight then take a nap. Everytime I do such a coding marathon and look at the code afterwards it is just a horrible mess and every error I had hard times to solve seemed just ridiculous. If you have the time for it get some temporal distance between you and the code and then have a look at it again.

Comment: Vague. "the list" What list? "the database" What database? "I want it to be highlighted" what's "it"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This selector `$(data)` doesn't make sense when you use it a second time. It creates a clone since data is not a selector, but (I'm guessing a string of HTML). You should instead only create one copy of your data, and add the effect to it:

```
$(data).prependTo('#ads').effect('highlight', {}, 5000);
```

[***Example JSFiddle post***](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/8kkHc/2/)

Comment: You know, you can add resources to fiddle posts without having to dump plugin code directly into your own. See the sidebar on the left.

Comment: I don't know where the effects plugin is hosted though. I just downloaded the code from here: http://jqueryui.com/download And plugged it in.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, I had to check which plugins I wanted to build a custom jQuery source.

Answer (score 0):

First `data` contains the rows you want to prepend. And in the second line `$(data)` should be the html items that contain that data? What if you prepend the data and give those lines a class that allows you to find those rose and give them a effect?